# Differentiating Rayleigh quotient

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> For a non symmetric real matrix $A$, differentiate $\frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}$, and hence find the stationary points-

**My attempt:** derivative = ${x^{T}(A+A^{T}) \over x^{T}x}-{2x^{T}Ax \over (x^{T}x)^2} x^{T}$

I've set to zero and simplified a bit but can't seem to get can't further.

I know the eigenvectors are the stationary points when A is symmetric but there's no answer on Google about the non symmetric case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f_A(x) = x^T Ax$ then $Df_A(x)h = x^T(A+A^T) h$.

If $d_A(x) = {1 \over f_A(x)}$, then $Dd_A(x)h =-{1 \over f_A^2(x)} x^T(A+A^T) h$.

If $h(x) = {f_A(x)  d_I(x)}$, then
\begin{align*}
Dh(x)h
& = \big({d_I(x)}Df_A(x) - f_A(x) D d_I(x)\big)h \\
& = \left({ 1 \over x^T x} x^T(A+A^T) - {2 \over (x^Tx)^2} x^T A x x^T\right)h.
\end{align*}

At a non zero stationary point $x$ we will have
$$
\left({ 1 \over x^T x} x^T(A+A^T) - {2 \over (x^Tx)^2} x^T A x x^T\right)
= 0,$$
or
$$
(A+A^T)x
= {2 \over x^T x} x x^T A^T  x
= {2 \over x^T x} x^T A^T  x x,
$$ that is, $x$ is an eigenvector of
$A+A^T$ corresponding to an eigenvalue
$$
\lambda
= {2 \over x^T x} x^T A^T  x
= {1 \over x^T x} x^T (A+A^T)  x.
$$